# Navigate programmatically in react-redux application using TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, react-router

Its been hours I am not finding a way or any good documentation which can show me how to navigate to any page programmatically. Here is my use case:
I have a login form, as soon as user login successfully, they should navigate to the account page, so I am trying to do this redirection from my actions, here is my code *(Note: I am using typescript)*:

```
/* Router.tsx */
const RouterComponent = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
                {/* <Route exact path="/" component={EmployeeList} /> */}
                <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}

/* App.tsx */
render () {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

        return (
            <Provider
                store={store}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>
        )
    }

/* Reducer */
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
export default combineReducers({
    auth: AuthReducer,
    account: AccountReducer,
    routing: routerReducer
})

/* Login action */
const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch: any, user: any) => {
    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user
    });

    // Here I want to add programmatic navigation 
}
```

I was trying to follow this doc: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux, but its using `browserHistory from 'react-router'` which is not available in `react-router`.

```
Versions:  
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2", 
"react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.8",
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `react-router-redux`

```
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
...
dispatch(push(`/account/${user.id}`));
```

Your App.tsx has an empty `<Router />` component that is not connected to redux because it is not nested inside a `<Provider>` tag.

```
/* App.tsx */
render () {
    const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

    return (
        <Provider
            store={store}>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
                    {/* <Route exact path="/" component={EmployeeList} /> */}
                    <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>                
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: it's not doing anything, do I have to make any changes in reducer? or somewhere else?

Comment: No, make sure the route you're pushing is valid. The one I provided is an example

Comment: I checked, and I am pushing valid route, but nothing is happening